# How to pass the awk variable in hdfs command

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop, awk, hdfs

I am listing the files/directories which are greather than N days using the below commands

```
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
dt=`date --date "$dt" +%Y%m%d`
loop_dt=`date -I --date "$dt -1 day"`   
*** output of loop_dt = 2018-02-25***

hdfs dfs -ls r /path/ | awk '$6 < "$loop_dt"'
```

I know the above hdfs command is wrong, But I want to pass the loop_dt varible in awk command, to know the list the files which are older than n days

Note: if I hardcode the date in awk command I am getting the results

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash

Comment: As mentioned by coddeforester be cautious about the **use of simple quotes and double quotes** in shells! Also in general, when you passe a variable to `awk` use this syntax: `awk -v awkVarName="$shellVariable" 'BEGIN {print awkVarName}'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To recap what I have said in the comments you need to fix your `awk` command in the following way:

```
$ cat file
2015-08-01
2015-08-13

$ awk -v var="2015-08-12" '{if( $1 < var"") print}' file                                                                                       
2015-08-01
```

Replace `2015-08-12` by your shell variable `"$loop_dt"` and it should work.

Explanations:

- Use this syntax `awk -v awkVarName="$shellVariable" 'BEGIN {print awkVarName}'` to pass a variable to `awk`
- In `if( $1 < var"")` the `""` force the string comparison.

Comment: hi in my scenario I don't want to print anything. I want to list the files based on date condition I am giving in the condition equal to $6( which is a date field )   hdfs dfs -ls -R /path/ | awk '$6 < "$loop_dt"'